# How to limit the number of selected tags displayed in the Select component in chakra ui

Tags: design-patterns, chakra-ui

Did Chakra UI's Select component have a  maxTagCount prop like in Antd
i wante to move up from this Design [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0yIB.png)
to this one [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOlde.png)

Did anybody have idea

`<Select size="sm" isMulti placeholder='Brand' />`